# How do I use execl when C file is in same directory as parent file

Tags: c, exec

I am trying to use execl to execute another C program, which is in the same directory as the parent file which calls the execl function.

I've tried using this code but it keeps saying **": No such file or directory"**.

```
execl("program", "program", (char*)NULL);
```

Comment: Maybe instead "program" you should use "./program" ... However this seems a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934947/linux-fork-exec-to-application-in-same-directory

Comment: nope doesn't work sadly

Comment: Then from the topic I referred to above this seems just right: Prepend the result of getcwd() to the executable name. However there are a lot of other alternatives presented there.